# Is it possible to find list of all the tables used in a SSIS package?

Tags: ssis

I need to find the list of all the tables used in a SSIS package. One way that I know of is to open the package in a textpad and search for the tables. But is there any reliable and fast way to do this using C# or some other technology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a reliable way to do this.  For example, tables can be referenced by variables that can change value at runtime or be amended via package configurations or values in a database.  So while you could look through the XML code for mentions of tables, you could not guarantee with would be 100% correct for any given package.  You could possibly look at running something like Profiler while the package is executing and then go through the output to see what tables were accessed and/or amended - this would be a very manual task however.