# Identify the dependant tables in SSIS packages

Tags: ssis

How to identify the dependent tables, columns, stored procedures, views , functions , parameters in SSIS packages ? Are there tools or queries available to fetch the information.

I have packages which have dependent tables and parameters. I am able to open the package and find it , however are there any tools which can help in scanning the whole package and providing the information ?
I have checked this - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26784.finding-ssis-packages-having-references-to-a-table-or-column.aspx , which needs the table and column information to be passed. However, there are times when this information is not available and the SSIS package needs to be fully scanned to provide the details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to find list of all the tables used in a SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231573/is-it-possible-to-find-list-of-all-the-tables-used-in-a-ssis-package)

Comment: Hi. Thanks, yes it seems to be a duplicate. But the other thread also does not have any solution.